# Compare a date and a timezone to a timestamptz in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, date, datetime

I have a table that contains a `date` column and a `varchar` column that contains a time zone. I would like to write a query that selects all rows where the date at midnight in the timezone is before a given `timestamp with time zone`.

For example, given

```
CREATE TABLE scheduled_tasks (
  id serial primary key,
  run_date date not null,
  customer_timezone varchar not null
 );

INSERT INTO scheduled_tasks(run_date, customer_timezone) VALUES 
  ('2017-10-15', 'America/Los_Angeles'),
  ('2017-10-15', 'America/New_York'),
  ('2017-10-15', 'Asia/Tokyo');
```

How would I write a query to find all `scheduled_tasks` that should be run at `2017-10-15T06:00:00Z`, given that I want each task to be run after midnight in its associated timezone? (So I want the Tokyo and New York tasks, but not the Los Angeles one, since `2017-10-15T06:00:00Z` is 11:00 PM on the 14th in LA.)

I see the `make_timestamptz` function, but is my best option really going to be:

```
SELECT *
FROM scheduled_tasks
WHERE make_timestamptz(
  EXTRACT (YEAR from run_date)::int,
  EXTRACT (MONTH from run_date)::int,
  EXTRACT (DAY from run_date)::int,
  0,
  0,
  0.0,
  customer_timezone) < '2017-10-15T06:00:00';
```

SqlFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/a8e38/4/0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT run_date::timestamp AT TIME ZONE customer_timezone < '2017-10-15T06:00:00Z'::timestamptz
FROM scheduled_tasks;
```

In this query I first create the time in particular timezone, then the expected run time at the UTC, and compare.

Comment: hello, i was trying your answer but when i try it on a `timestamp without time zone` column like this: `created at time zone '-06:00'` it subtracts 12 hours from the original, is there a way for it to not affect the time and date values ([which I understand PG always stores in UTC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53640516/4770813)), just change the timezone. i'm trying to compare dates and I'm trying to get them into the same tz first. thank you

Comment: @Scaramouche `at time zone` construct converts `timestamp` to `timestamptz` such as your original timestamp _already was_ on that timezone. If your original `timestamp` is in UTC then you should first attach UTC to it, and then convert it to needed zone: `(('2020-01-01T00:00:00'::timestamp) at time zone 'UTC') at time zone 'Europe/Oslo'`.